# Basic jTemplate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtemplate

I'm using jTemplate & jQuery to query a .net Web Method, then display the results in a webpage.

Shown below is the HTML where it all happens, the DIV with the class **Template** is my template. Then the actual results get put into the DIV with the class **Results**.

```
<div id="SharepointDocumentSearch" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        Document Search Results
    </p>
    <div class="Results">
        <i>Searching...</i>
    </div>
    <div class="Template" style="display:none;">
        {#foreach $T as document}
            <div>
                <a href="{$T.document.Url}" >{$T.document.Title}</a>
            </div>
        {#/for}
    </div>
</div>
```

I use jQuery to make an AJAX call, get the data back then run the following code:

```
$("#SharepointDocumentSearch>.Results").setTemplate($("#SharepointDocumentSearch>.Template").html());
$("#SharepointDocumentSearch>.Results").processTemplate(data.d);
```

Although the AJAX call is successful and the results are shown in the template, the URL doesn't get resolved by the templating engine. So the HTML renders is as follows:

```
<div class="Results">                                                    
    <div>                                
        <a href="%7B$T.document.Url%7D">Example 1.doc</a>                            
    </div>                                                   
    <div>                                
        <a href="%7B$T.document.Url%7D">Mercury documents</a>                            
    </div>                                            
</div>
```

The strange thing is, if I change the template so that it's putting the Url value instead a different attribute like 'Dog' for example, it'll appear in the HTML. It's just when I use it with the Url attribute this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bug**

Code doesn't run correctly in IETester IE6 instance, but works correctly on real IE6.